# Winform date search with 2 date time pickers access database

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I have Winform with 2 date time pickers that I search a date range in a Access database.

All was working well until today. When I search from 9/24/18 to 10/1/18 I don’t get any results.

The reason I’m guessing is the numeric order of the database.

Example : Dates are sorted based on the individual digits that make up the value, instead of on the numeric value. For example, the value 10/1/18 appears before 9/24/18. My Access database for the Date is set to Date. This is the Code

Thanks

```
private void btn_Range_Search_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string queryString = "SELECT HotSheetID, Today, Part, Timeord, Timerec, sdock, LCCN, Requestor, Notes, Type, Shift, RunOutTime, CICSTYPE FROM ILC,Reasontype WHERE Reasontype.typeID = ILC.typeID";

            queryString += string.Format(" AND ILC.Today BETWEEN '{0}' AND '{1}' ", dt3.Text, dt4.Text);  


            loadDataGrid(queryString);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must Refresh first before you can Search again!");
            return;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**DO NOT BUILD QUERY WITH `+ string` BUT PARAMETERS**

So rewrite your code to look like this (i will write whole SQL function so you rewrite your `loadDataGrid` based on it:

```
 using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
{
    con.Open();
    using(SqlDataAdapter da = new DataAdapter("SELECT HotSheetID, Today, Part, Timeord, Timerec, sdock, LCCN, Requestor, Notes, Type, Shift, RunOutTime, CICSTYPE FROM ILC,Reasontype WHERE Reasontype.typeID = ILC.typeID AND ILC.Today BETWEEN COALESCE(@date1, ILC.Today) AND COALESCE(@date2, ILC.Today)")
    {
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", dt3.Text); //Like this we pass parameters to query. In case of dates it will transform your date to correct format.
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", dt4.Text); //Like this we pass parameters to query. In case of dates it will transform your date to correct format.

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        //rest of the code
    }
}
```

As you can see in `query text` i have used `Coalesce`

`The COALESCE() function returns the first non-null value in a list.`

So now if we have condition with `SomeColumn = COALESCE(@ID, SomeColumn)` in c# we would "write" it like this (i do this so you understand function)

```
SomeColumn = (FirstValueInCoalesceFunction != null) ? firstValue : secondValue;
```

Now this is [short conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) which represents how  `Coalesce` works and if we pass `null` as parameter for `@ID` it will say `SomeColumn = SomeColumn` which will always be `TRUE`.

Also it would be good to use `yourDateTimePicker1.Value` instead of `dt3.Text` (if it is textBox but i suppose it is)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question - apply a proper format to the date values:

```
queryString += string.Format(" AND ILC.Today BETWEEN '{0}' AND '{1}' ", dt3.Value.ToString("#yyyy'/'MM'/'dd#"), dt4.Value.ToString("#yyyy'/'MM'/'dd#"));
```

That said, use parameters. Much easier to maintain and debug.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I will keep in mind and code better with Parmameter.

string queryString = "SELECT HotSheetID, Today, Part, Timeord, Timerec, sdock, LCCN, Requestor, Notes, Type, Shift, RunOutTime, CICSTYPE FROM ILC,Reasontype WHERE Reasontype.typeID = ILC.typeID AND ILC.Today BETWEEN # " + dt3.Value.ToShortDateString() + "# and #" + dt4.Value.ToShortDateString() + "#";